# How to handle non-existing value call for MongoDB find() in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

In PHP for an example

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('id' => $id));
if($cursor != null) {
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        //update
    }
}
else {
    //insert
}
```

If here this $id value is not in MongoDB table, then will it proceed to insert section in else. Otherwise how to handle response of such non-existing value of find method?

Comment: it's not very clear what you want it to do. You can do whatever you want if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I  had a look at the mongoDB reference and it appears that result sets have a length property. I'm not sure but I think you can use.

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('id' => $id));
if($cursor->count() > 0) {
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        //update
    }    
}else {
   //insert
}
```

If this doesn't work it's certainly a step in the right direction. Find the result set length.

Comment: Thanks a lot SOliver. I think this has to work. I will try that & let know.

Comment: Length can not be accessed like that. We have to use hasNext & proceed as AurelienB suggested

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the **upsert** option :
[MongoDB documentation here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29)

BTW I recommand you to use $cursor->**hasNext()** to know if your cursor has (more) result.